# Prolog: testing if bit is set

Tags: prolog, benchmarking, microbenchmark, sicstus-prolog

I'm using arbitrary-precision integers for representing dense bit-vectors—ranging in size
from a dozen up to a few thousand.

My code frequently needs to check if certain bits are set (or not),
so I did a few micro-benchmarks to see if some variations were significantly faster than others:

```
bench_1(0, _, _) :- !.
bench_1(N, V, P) :- V /\ (1 << P) =\= 0, N0 is N-1, bench_1(N0, V, P).

bench_2(0, _, _) :- !.
bench_2(N, V, P) :- (V >> P) /\ 1 =:= 1, N0 is N-1, bench_2(N0, V, P).

bench_3(0, _, _) :- !.
bench_3(N, V, P) :- (V >> P) /\ 1 =\= 0, N0 is N-1, bench_3(N0, V, P).

bench_4(0, _, _) :- !.
bench_4(N, V, P) :- (V >> P) /\ 1  >  0, N0 is N-1, bench_4(N0, V, P).

bench_5(0, _, _) :- !.
bench_5(N, V, P) :- 1 is (V >> P) /\  1, N0 is N-1, bench_5(N0, V, P).
```

Both with SWI and SICStus the above variants are all (almost) equally fast.

Then I stumbled upon the following [interesting part of the SWI-Prolog manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=arith):

> `getbit(+IntExprV, +IntExprI)`
>
> Evaluates to the bit value (`0` or `1`) of the `IntExprI`-th bit of `IntExprV`.
>      Both arguments must evaluate to non-negative integers.
>      The result is equivalent to `(IntExprV >> IntExprI)/\1`, but more efficient because materialization of the shifted value is avoided.
>
> **Future versions will optimise `(IntExprV >> IntExprI)/\1` to a call to `getbit/2`, providing both portability and performance.**

So I checked out `getbit/2`:

```
bench_6(0, _, _) :- !.
bench_6(N, V, P) :- getbit(V,P) =:= 1, N0 is N-1, bench_6(N0, V, P).
```

I used the following code for micro-benchmarkng:

```
call_indi_delta(G, What, Delta) :-
   statistics(What, [V0|_]),
   call(G),
   statistics(What, [V1|_]),
   Delta is V1 - V0.

run(Ind, Reps, Expr, Pos) :-
   Position is Pos,
   Value    is Expr,
   member(P_3, [bench_1,bench_2,bench_3,bench_4,bench_5,bench_6]),
   G =.. [P_3,Reps,Value,Position],
   call_indi_delta(G, Ind, T_ms), 
   write(P_3:Reps=T_ms), nl,
   false.
```

With `run(runtime, 10000000, 1<<1000-1, 200)` I observed these runtimes:

```
        | SWI    | SWI -O | SICStus | SICStus |
        | 7.3.23 | 7.3.23 |   4.3.2 |   4.3.3 |
--------+-----------------+-------------------|
bench_1 | 4547ms | 3704ms |   900ms |   780ms |
bench_2 | 4562ms | 3619ms |   970ms |   850ms |
bench_3 | 4541ms | 3603ms |   970ms |   870ms |
bench_4 | 4541ms | 3633ms |   940ms |   890ms |
bench_5 | 4502ms | 3632ms |   950ms |   840ms |
--------+-----------------+-------------------|
bench_6 | 1424ms |  797ms |    n.a. |    n.a. |
```

It appears that:

- **`getbit/2`** gave SWI-Prolog a **500% speedup**.
- The [command-line option `-O`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=cmdline) gave SWI-Prolog a remarkable speedup.

Is there some better formulation (arith. fun., etc.) to get a similar speedup with SICStus?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SWI-Prolog [uses `mpz_tstbit`](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/198feb84f2218c90f1d7d98eca6f1fe60375e3ff/src/pl-arith.c#L2680) from [GMP](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling.html) (look towards the bottom). Do you know how SICStus implements multiple-precision integers?

Comment: @Boris. I know GMP, but I don't know how SWI integrates it. (I'm still lost in the SWI sources.) Thank you for the links! About SICStus: I do not know that, but I have a hunch that the [tag:ffi] incurs some substantial calling overhead, but I'm not sure... I'll try the C interface to check that out.

Comment: SWI uses GMP for integers that get too big. If you grep for getbit in src/*.c you can find the line of code I linked.

Comment: @Boris. I got that. But how does it handle memory allocation? GMP allows registering custom allocators https://gmplib.org/manual/Custom-Allocation.html but with an important caveat: "*GMP may use allocated blocks to hold pointers to other allocated blocks. This will limit the assumptions a conservative garbage collection scheme can make.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I do not think that there are faster formulations than the ones you tried. In particular, there is nothing like `getbit/2` in SICStus (not even used internally when compiling arithmetics).

PS. I would use `walltime`, in general, for benchmarking. Current OSes do not provide a very reliable `runtime`.

PPS. I would add a benchmark that uses a dummy version of the tested code sequence, just to ensure that the tested code actually does cost much more than the benchmarking harness. (I did, and replacing the bit-test with a call to a `dummy/3` that does nothing, makes it much faster. So the benchmark seems OK.)

Comment: Thx! Should I try using the [tag:ffi]? IIRC the calling overhead appeared a bit on the high side with the JIT in SICStus 4.3.2 (64bit), has that changed?

Comment: I tried `walltime`, too. I expected to see noticable GC-overhead with big bit-vectors (IIRC GC-time is part of `walltime`). I was surprised that I didn't.

Comment: @repeat My guess is that fli would have too high overhead (and accessing the contents of the big integer from C is also not free) but it is hard to know without trying.